# Regex - check for character but not select it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing **swear words filter**, and I want to replace words with `*` for each character. But I want to replace only words and **not substrings** of words and also comas, dots, ... must stay on their original place.

Pleas take a look at **[this](http://www.regexr.com/39qe6) (working) example**. In this case I'm filtering word `f***`. First and second line are correctly selected, but other two aren't. In last case shout be selected all except `space`'s and similar in third case.

Comment: your example doesn't have any sample text

Comment: please also tag the question with the programming language OR program using regex OR regex-flavor

Comment: @datdo How do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really sound like regexes are well suited for solving your entire problem.  It might be easier to use regexes to find the swear words and then use code to do the replacement.

```
\b(swearword)\b
```

might be what you're looking for.  \b is a zero-width word boundary.

> ## [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
>
> Here is a example code below for doing it in JavaScript. **ES5 compatible!**
>
> ```js
> var filterRegex = /\b(swearword)\b/;
> var testString = "swearword";
>
> filterRegex.test(testString);
> ```